# From Mobile SF application To Mobile's section mobile

Tags: apex

I have a mobile application Salesforce, in the user details's page, there is an SMS boutton, when I click on, I have to choose a template (Text body) and click Send .
The button have to send me to my mobile' SMS section with the choosed the template.
I'm stuck in the last step . How can i get from a mobile salesforce to SMS section ?
Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a URL scheme to send an SMS message, but the problem is that this is not consistent between platforms.

On iOS it you are unable to pass in a formatted message with the number:

[Apple URL Scheme Reference - SMS Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH7-SW1)

On Android I have been able to send texts with a message as in this example. Note you have to do a URL encoded message:

[Send a SMS Text from a Link](http://demosthenes.info/blog/856/Send-a-SMS-Text-From-A-Link)